# MVC Update table mapping in Entity Framework, Error 2019

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a `db.edmx` containing all the values from the database.
Now initially I had the ID variables set to **int**, but since I started using Identity and wanting to link my tables into user ones I had to change the datatypes to **nvarchar(128)**
I've done that, updated my tables from the database, and changed all my classes to string like:

```
public partial class average
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string studentId { get; set; }
        public string classId { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime date { get; set; }

        public virtual @class @class { get; set; }
    }
```

But for some reason the table mapping keeps being set to **int32** like there:

[image]

Resulting in me getting an:

> Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.Int32[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'id' in type
>   'DbModel.average' is not compatible with
>   'SqlServer.nvarchar[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,MaxLength=128,Unicode=True,FixedLength=False,StoreGeneratedPattern=Identity]'
>   of member 'id' in type
>   'DbModel.Store.averages'. gimBook C:\Users\Alan\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\gimBook\gimBook\Models\Db.edmx   432

Another problem is that whenever I run `Update Model from Database` the `.cs` files automatically change all **strings** back into **int**.

Is there any way I could currectly update the mapping, so the values would work properly?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: Deleting the `db.edmx` file, and reimporing it seemed to fix the issue